# How user data stored on the eos blockchain is compliant with regulations?

Tags: multi-index, data-storage

I am exploring the eosio software, I was impressed with the ability of eosio of saving user data in a multi index table. While this property is technically really interesting I am trying to find use cases for that. Currently there exist regulations like GDPR who are considering how the user data is used. From my view storing user data (even if it is encrypted) in a blockchain does not seem to be a good idea, or maybe I have no a good use case for that.

Please could you guys help me clarify this topic?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, user data does not necessarily equal personal data and as long as you do not store personal data or something that falls under the GDPR on a public Blockchain you are ok.

It's simple, **let it be, don't store personal data on a public blockchain** (note what the GDPR says, there are many different sources for pseudonymisation and anonymisation under the GDPR). You can still store personal Data on a centralized server under GDPR-rules, if you need to.

If you really need/want to use a blockchain for personal data (there are a few cases where it makes sense, for example in the public administration), there are concepts like "pruning context-free-data" which can be used on a private network with trusted producer(s) which should allow you to be GPDR-compliant.
https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.1/nodeos/concepts/context-free-data/how-to-prune-context-free-data